# Two theorems about approximation by smooth functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. 
The following are two theorems taken from the chapter about Sobolev Spaces of the Evans' book.

**Theorem 1** *Assume $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$ for some $1\le p<\infty$ and set $u^{\varepsilon}=\eta_{\varepsilon}\ast u$ in $U_{\varepsilon}$, where $U_{\varepsilon}:= \{ x\in U: dist(x,\partial U)>\varepsilon\}$. Then*

- *$u^{\varepsilon}\in C^{\infty}(U_{\varepsilon})$ for each $\varepsilon >0$
  and*
- *$u^{\varepsilon}\to u$ in $W_{loc}^{k,p}(U)$ as $\varepsilon\to 0. $*

**Theorem 2** *Assume $U$ is bounded and suppose as well that $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$ for some $1\le p<\infty$. Then there exist functions $u_m\in C^{\infty}(U)\cap W^{k,p}(U)$ such that
$$ u_m\to u\qquad\text{  in}\,\,W^{k,p}(U).$$*

Our professor asked us to reflect about why Theorem 2 is more useful than Theorem 2. Theorem 1 states the conditions for a local approximation, while theorem 2 states the conditions for a global approximation.

I can't say anything else. Any ideas?